# Arduino temperature sensor

Tags: arduino, sensors, temperature

I am trying to build a small program with arduino using a temperature-sensor.

I thought I knew how to do it but I'm getting some weird outputs.

Here is my code:

```cpp
int sensorPin = 0;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
    int reading = analogRead(sensorPin);
    float voltage = reading * 5.0 / 1024;
    float temperatureC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100;
    Serial.print(temperatureC); Serial.print(" degrees C, ");
    Serial.print(voltage); Serial.println(" volts");
    delay(1000);
}
```

This code gives me the output:

```
-26.56 degrees C, 0.23 volts
-26.56 degrees C, 0.23 volts
-27.05 degrees C, 0.23 volts
-26.56 degrees C, 0.23 volts
-26.07 degrees C, 0.24 volts
-26.07 degrees C, 0.24 volts
```

Why is it `-` in degrees? and Why can I change it to any pin I want and it will still give me a similar output?

Comment: `float temperatureC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100;` If your voltage is 0.23 V: `(0.23-0.5)*100C=~-26C`

Comment: Please edit to indicate the Arduino board version you are using.  Also indicate the temperature sensor model.

Comment: Where did you get the `(voltage - 0.5) * 100` formula?

Answer (score 4):

Analog input 0 is not pin 0.

You should use the defined symbols:
**A0,A1,...,A7**
for analog inputs.

Try

```
int sensorPin = A0;
```

and your program should work.

If you are curious about the actual values, under your Arduino IDE install look in the file
..\hardware\arduino\variants\standard\pins_arduino.h

Answer (score 3):

You are reading this input correctly.
In order for you to not get negative degrees, you'll have to process it differently.

With this:

```cpp
float temperatureC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100;
```

Any values `< 0.5` result in multiplying a negative number by 100.

Try breaking this down using commutative property.

- `(voltage - 0.5) * 100` is the same as `(voltage * 100) - (0.5 * 100)`.
- This can be further simplified to `(voltage * 100) - 50`.

Still, for all values where `voltage < 0.5` the temperature will be negative.

- I would suggest multiplying `temperatureC` by `-1` to make it positive and not putting the sensor near anything that is `~ >= 50 degrees Celsius.

Also, As jdr5ca pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14192283/1440715), you're not actually getting any data from the sensor yet... `:(`

You are probably getting noise (or garbage) from whatever pin0 is.

**EDIT**

It is best practice to use parentheses to make order of operations more clear.

- **ie:**

  - `float voltage = reading * 5.0 / 1024;`
  - should be
  - `float voltage = reading * (5.0 / 1024);`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to use the defined symbols `A0`

```
int sensorPin = A0;

in the next

float voltage = reading * (5.0 / 1024);
```

There is an example in `File/Examples/Basic/AnalogReadSerial`